# boost beast async_write increases memory footprint dramatically

Tags: c++11, templates, gcc, boost, boost-beast

I am currently experimenting with the boost beast library and now very surprised by it's memory footprint. I've found out by using three different response types (string, file, dynamic) the program size grows up to 6Mb.

To get closer to the cause, I took the small server example from the library and reduced it to the following steps:

```
class http_connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<http_connection>
{
public:
    http_connection(tcp::socket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket)) { }
    void start() {
        read_request();
    }

private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_{8192};
    http::request<http::dynamic_body> request_;

    void read_request() {
        auto self = shared_from_this();
        http::async_read(
            socket_, buffer_, request_,
            [self](beast::error_code ec,
                std::size_t bytes_transferred)
            {
                    self->write_response(std::make_shared<http::response<http::dynamic_body>>());
                    self->write_response(std::make_shared<http::response<http::file_body>>());
                    self->write_response(std::make_shared<http::response<http::string_body>>(), true);
            });
    }

    template <class T>
    void write_response(std::shared_ptr<T> response, bool dostop=false) {

        auto self = shared_from_this();

        http::async_write(
            socket_,
            *response,
            [self,response,dostop](beast::error_code ec, std::size_t)
            {
                if (dostop)
                    self->socket_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send, ec);
            });
    }
};
```

when I comment out the three self->write_response lines and compile the program and execute the size command on the result, I get:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 343474    1680    7408  352562   56132 small
```

When I remove the comment of the first write, then I get:

```
 864740    1714    7408  873862   d5586 small
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
```

After removing all comments the final size become:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1333510    1730    7408 1342648  147cb8 small

4,8M Feb 16 22:13 small*
```

The question now is:

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a way to reduce the size?

**UPDATE**

the real process_request looks like:

```
void process_request() {

    auto it = router.find(request.method(), request.target());
    if (it != router.end()) {
        auto response = it->getHandler()(doc_root_, request);

        if (boost::apply_visitor(dsa::type::handler(), response) == TypeCode::dynamic_r) {
            auto r = boost::get<std::shared_ptr<dynamic_response>>(response);
            send(r);
            return;
        }
        if (boost::apply_visitor(dsa::type::handler(), response) == TypeCode::file_r) {
            auto r = boost::get<std::shared_ptr<file_response>>(response);
            send(r);
            return;
        }

        if (boost::apply_visitor(dsa::type::handler(), response) == TypeCode::string_r) {
            auto r = boost::get<std::shared_ptr<string_response>>(response);
            send(r);
            return;
        }
    }

        send(boost::get<std::shared_ptr<string_response>>(send_bad_response(
            http::status::bad_request,
           "Invalid request-method '" + std::string(req.method_string()) + "'\r\n")));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used beast but async IO puts the writes into memory if the destination isn't accepting writes. So, is your listener reading its inputs or just sitting there? And, if the network is going over something slow like WiFi it is very possible to stack up megabytes of RAM by writing entire files to the target. You will want to limit how much you buffer at a time and/or use OS APIs like sendfile.

Comment: Oh you're talking about the program's compiled size not runtime size. It's probably templates building lots of inline and duplicated code. Also exception and RTTI information. You could see if building in a release mode helps anything.

Comment: @Zan Lynx of course it is template stuff. I'm building with -o2 flag and without debug information.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to care about executable size? Or does this question come from a fear that 6MB executables are slower than 2MB executables?

Comment: @rubenvb for some reasons, I have to handle the individual connections in sub-processes (Forks). The performance of the forks depends very much on the executable size

Comment: @MohamedEl this is why we have shared libraries, no, to share code amongst executables in memory? I’m just not convinced you’re focusing on the main issue here.

Comment: @rubenvb as you know boost beast is a header only lib. My goal was to use it as is it without writing a shared lib as wrapper for some of its functions.

Comment: I have asked the question here to first make sure that the async_write really needs about 2Mb and nothing else (in this case I compile async_write separately as a shared lib and as plan B.

Comment: You can't call `async_write` twice in a row, you have to wait for the first one to complete before calling the second.

Comment: @VinnieFalco You're right, but the code is not for execution and just to illustrate the observed effect.

Comment: @MohamedEl You said "when I comment out the three self->write_response lines" which a reader might interpret literally. And if the code you provided is not representative of what you're actually running, it is unlikely we will be able to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: @VinnieFalco I updated the quetion with a small portion of my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't actually leaking memory, then there is nothing wrong. Whatever memory is allocated by the system will either be reused for your program or eventually given back. It can be very difficult to measure the true memory usage of a program, especially under Linux, because of the virtual memory system. Unless you see an actual leak or real problem, I would ignore those memory reports and simply continue implementing your business logic. Beast itself contains no memory leaks (tested extensively per-commit on Travis and Appveyor under valgrind, asan, and ubsan).

Answer (score 0):

Try  use `malloc_trim(0)` , ex: in destructor of `http_connection`.

from `man`:
malloc_trim - release free memory from the top of the heap.

The malloc_trim() function attempts to release free memory at the top of the heap (by calling sbrk(2) with a suitable argument).

The  pad  argument specifies the amount of free space to leave untrimmed at the top of the heap.

**If this argument is 0, only the minimum amount of memory is maintained at the top of the heap (i.e.,  one page or less)**.  A nonzero argument can be used to maintain some trailing space at the top of the heap in order to allow future allocations to be made without  having  to  extend  the  heap  with
       sbrk(2).